# How to get full path of shortcut link via vbscript

Tags: vbscript, shortcut, lnk

I have a vbscript in "D:\MyDoc\Script\MyScript.vbs"
with a shortcut link in "D:\Working\MyScript.vbs.lnk"

By double click the shortcut link, What code can I use to get the location of the shortcut link (ie. "D:\Working\MyScript.vbs.lnk")  NOT  the target path "D:\MyDoc\Script\MyScript.vbs"

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no way to get the location of the shortcut that started the script.
Although, a shortcut could pass this information to the script.
By including the location of the shortcut in the target propery of the shortcut like this:

```
D:\MyDoc\Script\MyScript.vbs "D:\Working\MyScript.vbs.lnk"
```

It would be possible to read out the location as a command line argument in the script:

```
WScript.Echo WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
```

Although this might not be the original purpose?

Comment: Further to alex-dl answer, is there any way to use "WScript.Echo WScript.Arguments.Item(0)" inside vbscript, or the other way round using vbscript code within WScript batch file. Thanks.